# Ubuntu 16.04: apache2.service start failed, segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: upgrade, apache2

Yesterday I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.2.

After the upgrade, my apache2 service would not start, error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I know there are many users who faced this, but not quite what I am facing.  There is no helpful error in the outputs. Just a generic segmentation failed error.

`systemctl status apache2.service`

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-04-12 22:13:22 SGT; 11s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 11446 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]:  *
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: Output of config test was:
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`journalctl -xe`

```
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 kernel: /usr/sbin/apach[11458]: segfault at 5 ip 00007f483f0db997 sp 00007ffd0d8f13e0 error 4 in Util.so[7f483f0d3000+b000]
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]:  *
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: Output of config test was:
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 apache2[11446]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 12 22:13:22 ip-172-31-15-210 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've tried purging and installing apache2, libapache2-mod-php7.0, libapache2-mod-perl. There is no php5 installed (Ubuntu removed it during the upgrade.)

Anyone have any opinions on what else can I do?

**EDIT 1:**
Using gdb on the core dump gives this:

```
[New LWP 12661]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -t'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fb84d424997 in boot_List__Util (my_perl=0x5595f24c3840, 
    cv=0x5595f27e76e0) at ListUtil.c:1793
1793        dVAR; dXSARGS;
```

Comment: What is in your apache2-systemd.conf file?  Have you had a look at the core dump files using something like `gdb /path/to/application /path/to/corefile` ?  Are you able to re-install php5, or any other PHP packages/versions?

Comment: Did you try to do a config test and see if there's something wrong? Try using :
apachectl configtest

Comment: @FCTW apache2-systemd.conf contents:
`    [Service]
    Type=forking
    RemainAfterExit=no`
There's no libapache2-mod-php5* package available, so can't install anything but 7.0

Comment: @Adonist It gives:
===
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
===
apache error log is empty

Comment: I've edited the original question to include gdb output on the core dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an answer here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310952/upgraded-ubuntu-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts-and-bugzilla-stopped-working/43438371#43438371

I had decided to disable all apache config and enable one by one. And apache2 reload failed when I enabled the Bugzilla-specific config.  Looks like it's perl modules were conflicting with Ubuntu 16.04.  I used CPAN to update perl modules, renamed bugzilla/lib to bugzilla/lib.old and ran bugzilla/checksetup.pl.

The script recreated the bugzilla/lib contents, and apache2 reload was successful.